# Rosetta 2 installation on M1 MBP fails

Tags: terminal, install, big-sur, rosetta-2

I'm trying to install rosetta 2 via command line, using this command:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Source: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/11/17/installing-rosetta-2-on-apple-silicon-macs/

**The problem:**

I'm receiving this error:

```
softwareupdate[981:12251] Package Authoring Error: 001-79711: Package reference com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto is missing installKBytes attribute
```

**Terminal screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

**The question:**
How can I get rid of this error and install rosetta 2 properly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123059/discussion-on-question-by-tmuecksch-rosetta-2-installation-on-m1-mbp-fails).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't know about the error message but the command also reports `Install of Rosetta 2 finished successfully`. So to check whether Rosetta actually got installed

- Install an "old" application not recompiled for M1 yet (if you don't have one, any free application from the Store which hasn't been updated since May 2020 will do)
- Run it to see if it works.

You can then also check in Activity Monitor by enabling the "Architecture" column there. If any process shows as"Intel", Rosetta is installed

Comment: got same error, appeared to install without issue.